# Referencia de objeto no establecida en una instancia de un objeto en InitializeEditingControlValue de un DataGridView

Tags: c#

```
private void dgvDetalle_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            FilaActual = dgvDetalle.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
            if (dgvDetalle.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 1)
            {
                ComboBox cb = e.Control as ComboBox;
                cb.SelectedIndexChanged -= new EventHandler(cb_SelectedIndexChanged);
                cb.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
                cb.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown;
                cb.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
                cb.AutoCompleteCustomSource = scProductosListaSugeridos;
                cb.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(cb_SelectedIndexChanged);
            }
        }
        catch { }

    }


private void cb_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            ComboBox cb = (ComboBox)sender;
            ProductoCodigo = Convert.ToInt32(cb.SelectedValue);
            enProducto = lnProductos.ProductoBuscar(ProductoCodigo);
            enMedida = lnProductos.MedidaBuscar(enProducto.MedidaCodigoUso);
            dgvDetalle.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value = $"{ProductoCodigo}";
            dgvDetalle.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value = $"{enMedida.Nombre}".Trim();
            dgvDetalle.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value = "0";
            dgvDetalle.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Selected = true;
            dgvDetalle.CurrentCell = dgvDetalle.Rows[FilaActual].Cells[3];
            SendKeys.Send("{F2}");
        }
        catch { }
}
```

Tengo un datagridview con una columna de tipo comboboxcolumn, todo funciona a la perfección pero al momento de tratar de seleccionar un elemento de la lista sugerida y terminar por no seleccionar ningun item, luego moverme a otra celda y regresar a la celda de combboxcolumn y presiona una letra para buscar ocurre el error siguiente:

"Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto."
"   en

> System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.InitializeEditingControlValue(DataGridViewCellStyle& dataGridViewCellStyle, DataGridViewCell dataGridViewCell)\r\n   en System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.BeginEditInternal(Boolean selectAll)\r\n   en System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.ProcessKeyEventArgs(Message& m)\r\n   en System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmKeyChar(Message& m)\r\n   en System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)\r\n   en System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)\r\n   en System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)\r\n   en System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)\r\n   en System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)\r\n   en System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)\r\n   en Presentacion.Program.Main() en C:\Mika\DataAcces\Presentacion\Program.cs:línea 30"
>   Application.Run(new InvExamenComponentes());

De antemano les envió las gracias por su valiosa ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

El problema que observo es que utilizas un caste al tipo `ComboBox` sin valdar si pudo hacerlo correctamente.

Cuando usas esto

```
ComboBox cb = e.Control as ComboBox;
```

tienes que validar si pudo convertir usando

```
if(cb == null){
   return;
}
```

la idea es no continuar porque `cb` quedara sin instanciar (la variable en null) por lo tanto obtendras justamente ese mensaje de error si intentas acceder alguna propiedad o metodo, que es justamente lo que realizas

Por otro lado **NUNCA** definas un `try` con un `catch` vacio, es una pesima practica, al menos loguea el problema o tratalo de alguna forma

Comment: Gracias Leandro, ya entendí cual era mi problema.
Saludos.